# Prolog split list by predicate - how to check predicate's result?

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to implement a predicate that splits a list of integers in two given another predicate as an argument. The definition is given as follows:

```
split(P, L, L1, L2),
```

where:

```
P - predicate to split upon
L - list to split
L1 - result list of integers that return true on predicate check
L2 - result list of integers that return false on predicate check
```

I am trying to modify this code, that splits the list with hardcoded check whether the integer in question is bigger / smaller or equal to X (this works):

```
split(X, [], [], []).
split(X, [H|T], [H|L1], L2) :- H=<X, split(X, T, L1, L2).
split(X, [H|T], L1, [H|L2]) :- H>X, split(X, T, L1, L2).
```

For testing purposes, I copied a predicate from RosettaCode to check if the number is even as follows:

```
even(N) :-
 (between(0, inf, N); integer(N) ),
 0 is N mod 2.
```

And here is my modification of the above code, but it returns "Syntax error: Operator expected" on last two lines:

```
split2(P, [], [], []).
split2(P, [H|T], [H|L1], L2) :- P(H), split2(P, T, L1, L2).
split2(P, [H|T], L1, [H|L2]) :- \+ P(H), split2(P, T, L1, L2).
```

I think my error is in checking whether the predicate returns true or false, but can't find the appropriate way of doing so.

EDIT: Forgot to add my call for this:

```
 ?- split2(even,[2,7,4,8,-1,5],L1,L2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a predicate like this, you need to use `call`:

```
?- A = between(0,3,1), A. % OK, because A can be evaluated as it is
A = between(0, 3, 1).

?- A = between, A(0,3,1). % won't work
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: A = between, 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: A(0,3,1) . 
?- A = between, call(A, 0, 3, 1). % OK, using call
A = between.

?- A = between(0, 3), call(A, 1). % Partial application
A = between(0, 3).
```

Keep in mind that there are already library predicates that do exactly what you are after, see [`library(apply)`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply), esp. `include/3`. You should also take a look [at the implementation](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/apply.pl?show=src#include/3), as it is slightly different from what you are doing and doesn't leave choice points behind.

PS: Rearranging the arguments so that the input list is at the front is the first step towards making this deterministic. You also need to get rid of the choice point caused by the two clauses, the one with `call(P,H)` and the one with `\+ call(P,H)`. You can do this with a `->`, as in the SWI-Prolog library.

Or maybe you are not bothered by the choice points, or want to make a more general predicate. I am sure that there are solutions here on Stackoverflow on the Prolog tag.

Comment: "_there are already library predicates that do exactly what you are after_" - I suppose so, but I would like to write ones myself to learn Prolog. If you could elaborate more on your answer I would be very grateful. As you may see from my question, I'm new to Prolog and I don't really know how to fix this, any help is most appreciated (I try to Google this out, but it's hard when you don't know what to search for). Does the fix to my question requires a lot of changes?

Comment: @Asunez please re-read my answer. I reproduce your error using a simplified example and show you how to correct it.

Comment: @Asunez If you cared to click on the links I provided, especially the one that shows the implementation of `include/3`, you will see an example of how to use `call` in order to evaluate a predicate. Reading other people's code is one of the most fundamental ways of learning how to program.